# Convert multi column MySql records to responsive display

Tags: mysql, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, responsive

I've been racking my brain trying to make a listing of members in a website that I used tables in the past to be responsive. I want to design a new site with Bootstrap but just can't seem to find the proper way to get the records to format the same way I had it before. Right now it's locked in with 4 across but if I can get the records to fill the available width, that would be ok. Can anyone help?

Here is the code I used in html to display:

```
<!-- access ppocc_members -->
<?php require_once('Connections/ppocc_members.php'); ?>
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_ppocc_members, $ppocc_members);
$query_ppoccfrontpage = "SELECT id, uploaded_file_name, StudioName, Phone1, `Website URL` FROM form_results WHERE CurrentMember = 'yes' AND form_results.WebsiteAd = 'yes' ORDER BY RAND() ";
$ppoccfrontpage = mysql_query($query_ppoccfrontpage, $ppocc_members) or die(mysql_error());
$row_ppoccfrontpage = mysql_fetch_assoc($ppoccfrontpage);
$totalRows_ppoccfrontpage = mysql_num_rows($ppoccfrontpage);
?>
<!-- end access ppocc_members -->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test Member Database</title>
</head>

<body>



    <p align="left"><font color="#879ECB" size="6" face="Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif">W</font><font color="#666666" size="3" face="Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif">elcome
        to the Professional Photographers of Cape Cod website, where you can
        find the most extensive list on the net of over 20 Cape Cod
      professional photographers and videographers 
      specializing <br>
      in all areas
        of photography as well as videography. <a href="members/findaphotographer_speciality.php">Find
        a Photographer</a>, and other
      information for <br>
      Brides &amp; Grooms, families, seniors and others interested in the finest
      photography
offered <br>
by many of Cape Cod's most experienced photographers.<br> 
    </font><font size="3" face="Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif"><br>
<font color="#879ECB" size="2">Click on any image below to get more information about a member studio</font></font><font color="#666699" size="3" face="Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif"> </font></p>
    <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" >
  <!--DWLayoutTable-->
  <tr>
    <?php
$ppoccfrontpage_endRow = 0;
$ppoccfrontpage_columns = 4; // number of columns
$ppoccfrontpage_hloopRow1 = 0; // first row flag
do {
    if($ppoccfrontpage_endRow == 0  && $ppoccfrontpage_hloopRow1++ != 0) echo "<tr>";
   ?>
    <td width="184" height="218" align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><p align="center"><a href="members/details2.php?recordID=<?php echo $row_ppoccfrontpage['id']; ?>">      <img src="members/files/<?php echo $row_ppoccfrontpage['uploaded_file_name']; ?>" alt="Click For More Details" name="StudioImage" border="0"></a></p>      
      <p align="center"><a href="members/details2.php?recordID=<?php echo $row_ppoccfrontpage['id']; ?>"><font color="#879ECB" size="1" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><em><font color="#999999">Studio
              Profile</font></em><strong><br>
              <?php echo $row_ppoccfrontpage['StudioName']; ?></strong></font></a><a href="details2.php?recordID=<?php echo $row_ppoccfrontpage['id']; ?>"><font color="#000000" size="1" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><br>
              </font></a><font color="#999999" size="1" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $row_ppoccfrontpage['Phone1']; ?><br>
            </font><font color="#999999" size="2" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><a href="<?php echo $row_ppoccfrontpage['Website URL']; ?>" target="_blank"><font size="1"><em>Visit
            Website</em><br>  
            <font color="#000000"><?php echo $row_ppoccfrontpage['StudioName']; ?></font></font></a></font></p>
    </td>
    <?php  $ppoccfrontpage_endRow++;
if($ppoccfrontpage_endRow >= $ppoccfrontpage_columns) {
  ?>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="13"></td>
    </tr>
  <?php
 $ppoccfrontpage_endRow = 0;
  }
} while ($row_ppoccfrontpage = mysql_fetch_assoc($ppoccfrontpage));
if($ppoccfrontpage_endRow != 0) {
while ($ppoccfrontpage_endRow < $ppoccfrontpage_columns) {
    echo("<td>&nbsp;</td>");
    $ppoccfrontpage_endRow++;
}
echo("</tr>");
}?>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

This is my current website that uses the mysql.
www.ppocc.org

Answer (score 0):

When using Bootstrap you should use the *grid system* instead of tables.

Bootstrap v4 example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

Here is [Bootstraps documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/).

Please note that the classes have changed dramatically in v4, so if you are using another version you should refer to that versions documentation on the *grid system*.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried different ways in Bootstrap but either I just get the data in only one column, or I can use the above code and get 4 columns but it's not responsive. I need a way to display the data like I used to, placing each record next to each other instead of in one column.

Comment: The above code should give you 4 columns. Which version of bootstrap are you using? It doesn't looks like you are including bootstrap css in your above code.

Comment: HI, I did try it with bootstrap but I could only get it to display either just one column with all the records or my above layout with 4 records across. In my old code  (   $ppoccfrontpage_columns = 4; // number of columns  ) sets the number of records across. I am looking for an alternative to the code I already have. Thanks

Comment: Here is a link to the Bootstrap version I tried it in: http://ppocc.org/ppocc/index2017test3.php

Comment: @MarkO'Connell: Bootstrap v3: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid